# Load application settings from external file

Tags: angular, angular5, settings

I'm developing a Single Page Application in Angular that will connect with external services. However, I don't any warranties that path for those services will remain the same. My goal is to save those settings in an external settings file so I could update them on the fly without having to recompile and redeploy my app every time a path changes.

In Java using Spring framework using `.properties`files it would be something like

```java
public class RemoteService{
    @Value("${removeservice.address}")
    private String address;

    // Class logic
}
```

How could I do the same thing in Java?

Comment: I don't understand, you are just looking for a config file to store your API's url or some configuration informations ?

Comment: @Moug It's exactly that! I want to save some of the URLs (and maybe other flags) on config file and load its contents on my Components/Services.

Answer (score 2):

**[OLD]**

In angular you have "environment" files which let you store some datas like URLs of your APIs , see :

- https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/
- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#the-src-folder

use like this example :
in your src/environments/environment.dev.ts file you can expose a const like :

```
export const environment = {
    apiUrl: 'http://my-api.domain.com'
}
```

which can be used like

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export class MyService{

    private url = environment.apiUrl;

}
```

ps: you have to tell angular your environment files in the angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [
***
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments":{
    "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts"
}
***
}
```

and if you really want to keep your Java syntaxe you can look for create javascript "decorator"

**[EDITED]**

I don't think there is a real solution, you can do it by hand, to avoid rebuild, create another config file (not in environments ), and load this config file datas into a service before the app to be initialized by using the "APP_INITIALIZER" token when you provide the service.

you can find an example to try here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-config-at-runtime

Tell me if it helped you.

The solution came from a co-worker of mine [Jonathan Antoine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183942/jonatha-antoine), not my code, you can find a blog post about it here (warning it's in french but you can see code ): https://blogs.infinitesquare.com/posts/web/angular-ajouter-une-configuration-chargee-au-runtime-post-build-plutot-que-pendant-la-build

Comment: If I use environment variables and I need to change one in production, I have to re-build and re-deploy my application, correct? Because that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @TiagoLeite That's correct. This usage of the environment config doesn't really seem to be for what it was originally intended to be honest. A better method of doing stuff like passing in endpoint urls and other config that changes per website to which you may be deploying is to load some kind of json settings file that is not baked into the application at build. You can have an angular service that runs at your application start, loads the settings, and then makes them available to any other services that may need them. I know this is pretty old now, so I assume you've probably solved this.